# jenkinsfile, load and variables scope

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I got an error this last Friday when trying to use [load](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) within a Jenkinsfile pipeline and can't get it out of my mind why it doesn't work.

In my setup there is a Jenkins master and some slaves. I have an external Groovy script that processes JSON files depending on some conditions. Checking out documentation, the procedure is to load the Groovy script meanwhile in the master, before submitting the job to an agent.

**Updated due request**

I provide a more realist test here. I tested this against a single, local Jenkins server, version 2.107.2.

Code to be loaded:

```
class Foobar {
    private name = 'foobar'
    private now

    Foobar() {
        this.now = new Date()
    }

    String say() {
        "My name is $name and I was created at $now"    
    }

}

def build_foobar() {
    new Foobar()
}

return this
```

The pipeline:

```
def foobar

node() {
    foobar = load '/tmp/foobar.groovy'
    println "After load: $foobar"
}

node() {
    stage('checkout') {
        println 'checkout from scm'
    }
    stage('build') {
        println "at build: $foobar"
        testing()
    }
}

def testing() {
    println "at testing: $foobar"
    def foo = foobar.build_foobar()
    println foobar.say()
}
```

When I try to execute it, `foobar` generates a binding exception, like if I didn't declared pipeline before, even though I applied `return this` to the end of 'foobar.groovy':

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foobar for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.testing(WorkflowScript:22)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:16)
```

In order to do some debugging, I enabled the `println` over the code, and was able to get `Script1@XXXXX`, meaning that the code was read, parsed and compiled as expected. If I pass `foobar` as a parameter to `testing()`, this works as expected:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/teste
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (/tmp/foobar.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] echo
Script1@150cc39b
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/teste
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (checkout scm)
[Pipeline] echo
checkout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] echo
at build: Script1@150cc39b
[Pipeline] echo
at testing: Script1@150cc39b
[Pipeline] echo
My name is foobar and I was created at Mon May 07 09:15:15 BRT 2018
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Now, that's a different behavior when I have a master and slave nodes. The only way to get this code running in the slave (after `load` from master) is to forget about `foobar()` and execute the pipeline methods inside the slave node, all works as expected. Of course, this undesirable since I'm just copying n' pasting code instead of reusing it.

What I'm missing over there?

Comment: Can you provide an example of contents of `pipeline.groovy`? Also, `pipeline` not be the best name because it shadows the name of the `pipeline`  from declarative pipelines.

Comment: I updated the code @mkobit.